# Итерация первого элемента массива

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

```js
$(".room-guests-count").click(function(e){
 $(".form-open").toggle();
 e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.form-open').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
  $('.form-open').hide();
});

const room = document.querySelector('.room-guests-count');
const form = document.querySelector('.form-open');
const adultsChildren = document.querySelector('.adults-children');
const adultsChildrenWrapper = document.querySelector('.adults-children-wrapper');

// let roomCount = document.querySelectorAll("room-count");
let roomCount = document.querySelectorAll(".room-count");

   
// roomCount.style.backgroundColor = "red";

let formIsOpened = false;

room.onclick = () => {
  if(!formIsOpened) {
    form.style.display = 'block'
  } else {
    form.style.display = 'none'
  }
  formIsOpened = !formIsOpened;
}
const toggleRoom = () => {
  const addRoomButton = document.querySelector('#add-room');
  const removeRoomButton = document.querySelector('#remove-room');
  const countRoom = document.querySelector('.form-text');
  
  const addSection = () => {
    const wrapper = document.createElement("div"); //Создает новый элемент с указанным тегом:
    wrapper.className = "adults-children-wrapper"; // имя класса добавить к елементу
    // const template = adultsChildrenWrapper.innerHTML; // значение  adultsChildrenWrapper присваивается к template
    wrapper.innerHTML = adultsChildrenWrapper.innerHTML; // значение  adultsChildrenWrapper присваивается к wrapper                
    adultsChildren.appendChild(wrapper);
    
      
  }
  const removeSection = () => {
    adultsChildren.lastChild.remove();
  }
  
  addRoomButton.onclick = () => {
    if(countRoom.value == 4) return;
    countRoom.value++;

    roomCount[0].textContent++;

    // roomCount.textContent++;
    // if (countRoom.value >= 2)
    addSection();
    
  }

  removeRoomButton.onclick = () => {
    if(countRoom.value == 1) return;
    countRoom.value--;
    roomCount[0].textContent--;
    
    removeSection();
  }
  
  
}
toggleRoom();
```

```css
* {
  background:lightblue;
}
/*ROOM GUESTS COUNT*/
.room-guests-count {
 width: 17.2%;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-right: 4%;
 background: #fff;
 float: right;
 height: 66px;
 margin-right: 149px;
}
.form-open {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 top: 110px;
 background-color: #fff;
 height: auto;
 right: -8px;
 width: 348px;
}

.form-open:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 right: 300px;
 top: -10px;
}
.room-guests-content {
 padding-top: 23px;
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.click_hidden_text {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 left: 163px;
 top: 56px;
 opacity: 0.8;
}
.form-search {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
 
}
.form-item {
 padding: 10px 5px;
 clear: both;
 height: 14px;
}
.edit-rooms {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 float: left;
 color: #000;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.rooms-guests-plus {
 float: right;
 color: #fff;
 background:#ccc;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 24px;
 top: -6px;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 18px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.form-text {
 text-align: center;
 width: 6%;
 width: 20px !important;
 text-decoration: center;
 float: right;
 border:0;
 padding: 0;
 height: auto;
 outline: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.textfield label {
 margin-right: 2.5px;
 display: inline;
 font-size: 13px;
}
.children-1 label {
 display: inline;
 font-size: 13px;
}
.rooms-guests-minus {
 float: right;
 color: #fff;
 background:#e7e7e7;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 24px;
 top: -6px;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 18px;
 cursor:auto;
}
.adults-children {
 clear: both;
}
.rooms-id {
 line-height: 40px;
 float: left;
 padding:5px 0 0 15px;
 color: #000;
}
.already-min {
 float: right;
 margin: -16px 0px 2px 6px;
 padding: 0;
 background: #fff;
}
.already-min-search {
 float: right;
 margin: 5px 10px 5px 2px;
}
.adults-children-wrapper {
 clear: both;
}
.children-1 {
 padding: 10px 5px;
 clear: both;
 height: 14px;
}
.edit-children {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 float: left;
 color: #000;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.textfield {
 clear: both;
 height: 14px;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 32px;
}
/*FORM FINISHED*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="room-guests-count">
  <div class="room-guests-content">
    Взрослых
    <span class="ga-count">2</span>
    , Детей 
    <span class="children-count">0</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-open">
  <div class="form-search">
    <div class="form-item">
      <label class="edit-rooms">Количество номеров</label>
      <div class="rooms-guests-plus" id="add-room">+</div>
      <input type="text" name="rooms" max="9" min="1" maxlength="128" class="form-text" value="1" size="60" readonly="readonly">
      <div class="rooms-guests-minus" id="remove-room">-</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="adults-children">
    <div class="adults-children-wrapper">
      <div class="rooms-id">Номер <span class="room-count">1</span>:</div>
      <div class="already-min-search">
        <div class="children-1">
          <label for="edit-children">Детей</label>
          <div class="rooms-guests-plus">+</div>
          <input type="text" name="childrenqt" value="0" max="5" min="0" maxlength="5" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
          <div class="rooms-guests-minus">-</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="already-min">
        <div class="textfield">
          <label for="edit">Взрослых</label>
          <div class="rooms-guests-plus">+</div>
          <input type="text" name="edit" value="2" max="10" min="0" maxlength="5" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
          <div class="rooms-guests-minus">-</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Всем привет.Есть такой не сложный код.При клике на + создается блок синхронно плюс как видите первый элемент считает число всех блоков.А все остальные блоки работают стабильно.Испробовал все что знаю чтобы  исправить включая цикл for

```
for(var i = 1;i < roomCount.length;i++){
   roomCount[i].textContent++;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для того чтоб работало достаточно попробовать такой вариант:

- к `adultsChildren.appendChild(wrapper)` добавить
  `.querySelector(".room-count").innerText = countRoom.value;` (т.е менять мы уже будем содержимое скопированного Wrapper'a, а не оригинала)
- а `roomCount[0].textContent++;` и `roomCount[0].textContent--;`
  вообще удалить

я понимаю это экспериментальный код , но в нём очень много лишнего сейчас

```js
$(".room-guests-count").click(function(e){
 $(".form-open").toggle();
 e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.form-open').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
  $('.form-open').hide();
});

const room = document.querySelector('.room-guests-count');
const form = document.querySelector('.form-open');
const adultsChildren = document.querySelector('.adults-children');
const adultsChildrenWrapper = document.querySelector('.adults-children-wrapper');

// let roomCount = document.querySelectorAll("room-count");
let roomCount = document.querySelectorAll(".room-count");

   
// roomCount.style.backgroundColor = "red";

let formIsOpened = false;

room.onclick = () => {
  if(!formIsOpened) {
    form.style.display = 'block'
  } else {
    form.style.display = 'none'
  }
  formIsOpened = !formIsOpened;
}
const toggleRoom = () => {
  const addRoomButton = document.querySelector('#add-room');
  const removeRoomButton = document.querySelector('#remove-room');
  const countRoom = document.querySelector('.form-text');
  
  const addSection = () => {
    const wrapper = document.createElement("div"); //Создает новый элемент с указанным тегом:
    wrapper.className = "adults-children-wrapper"; // имя класса добавить к елементу
    // const template = adultsChildrenWrapper.innerHTML; // значение  adultsChildrenWrapper присваивается к template
    wrapper.innerHTML = adultsChildrenWrapper.innerHTML; // значение  adultsChildrenWrapper присваивается к wrapper                
    
      adultsChildren.appendChild(wrapper).querySelector(".room-count").innerText = countRoom.value;
      
  }
  const removeSection = () => {
    adultsChildren.lastChild.remove();
  }
  
  addRoomButton.onclick = () => {
    if(countRoom.value == 4) return;
    countRoom.value++;

    

    // roomCount.textContent++;
    // if (countRoom.value >= 2)
    addSection();
    
  }

  removeRoomButton.onclick = () => {
    if(countRoom.value == 1) return;
    countRoom.value--;
   
    
    removeSection();
  }
  
  
}
toggleRoom();
```

```css
* {
  background:lightblue;
}
/*ROOM GUESTS COUNT*/
.room-guests-count {
 width: 17.2%;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-right: 4%;
 background: #fff;
 float: right;
 height: 66px;
 margin-right: 149px;
}
.form-open {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 top: 110px;
 background-color: #fff;
 height: auto;
 right: -8px;
 width: 348px;
}

.form-open:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 right: 300px;
 top: -10px;
}
.room-guests-content {
 padding-top: 23px;
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.click_hidden_text {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 left: 163px;
 top: 56px;
 opacity: 0.8;
}
.form-search {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
 
}
.form-item {
 padding: 10px 5px;
 clear: both;
 height: 14px;
}
.edit-rooms {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 float: left;
 color: #000;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.rooms-guests-plus {
 float: right;
 color: #fff;
 background:#ccc;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 24px;
 top: -6px;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 18px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.form-text {
 text-align: center;
 width: 6%;
 width: 20px !important;
 text-decoration: center;
 float: right;
 border:0;
 padding: 0;
 height: auto;
 outline: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.textfield label {
 margin-right: 2.5px;
 display: inline;
 font-size: 13px;
}
.children-1 label {
 display: inline;
 font-size: 13px;
}
.rooms-guests-minus {
 float: right;
 color: #fff;
 background:#e7e7e7;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 24px;
 top: -6px;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 18px;
 cursor:auto;
}
.adults-children {
 clear: both;
}
.rooms-id {
 line-height: 40px;
 float: left;
 padding:5px 0 0 15px;
 color: #000;
}
.already-min {
 float: right;
 margin: -16px 0px 2px 6px;
 padding: 0;
 background: #fff;
}
.already-min-search {
 float: right;
 margin: 5px 10px 5px 2px;
}
.adults-children-wrapper {
 clear: both;
}
.children-1 {
 padding: 10px 5px;
 clear: both;
 height: 14px;
}
.edit-children {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 float: left;
 color: #000;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.textfield {
 clear: both;
 height: 14px;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 32px;
}
/*FORM FINISHED*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="room-guests-count">
  <div class="room-guests-content">
    Взрослых
    <span class="ga-count">2</span>
    , Детей 
    <span class="children-count">0</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-open">
  <div class="form-search">
    <div class="form-item">
      <label class="edit-rooms">Количество номеров</label>
      <div class="rooms-guests-plus" id="add-room">+</div>
      <input type="text" name="rooms" max="9" min="1" maxlength="128" class="form-text" value="1" size="60" readonly="readonly">
      <div class="rooms-guests-minus" id="remove-room">-</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="adults-children">
    <div class="adults-children-wrapper">
      <div class="rooms-id">Номер <span class="room-count">1</span>:</div>
      <div class="already-min-search">
        <div class="children-1">
          <label for="edit-children">Детей</label>
          <div class="rooms-guests-plus">+</div>
          <input type="text" name="childrenqt" value="0" max="5" min="0" maxlength="5" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
          <div class="rooms-guests-minus">-</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="already-min">
        <div class="textfield">
          <label for="edit">Взрослых</label>
          <div class="rooms-guests-plus">+</div>
          <input type="text" name="edit" value="2" max="10" min="0" maxlength="5" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
          <div class="rooms-guests-minus">-</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное.Есть 2 вопроса?Что тут лишнего к примеру ?Во вторых как вы это сделали?То есть я начал решать эту задачу с утра и потратил весь рабочий день и всеравно сдалсья и написал тут как вам удается решать такие задачи не пойму может у меня мало стажа 2 месяца всево то работаю и всегда удевляюсь когда тут отвечают на мои вопросы .